# How useful are tags like "simple" in Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, meta-tags

I am not sure how much these kinds of tags are helping:

- [simple](/questions/tagged/simple)
- [student](/questions/tagged/student)
- etc.

Is their use encouraged on Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are meta tags and should be [discouraged with extreme prejudice](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/).

If you have retag or edit rights remove them - but be careful. I checked [simple](/questions/tagged/simple) and there are some on the first page that should be something like [simple-loop] (though seeing it written down I'm not so sure), so a straight delete isn't always appropriate.

Bringing them to the attention of the wider community is a good thing.

Comment: Well that answers the question, thanks!! BTW there use is quite spread, should this be solved or is it "from now on"?

Comment: @Trufa - meta tags should be removed to discourage/stop their use. If there's one tag in the system it can be reused. By removing them all they don't get suggested and low rep users can't recreate them. High rep users *should* know better.

Comment: Seeing your edit, I agree that some might be useful (if I see complex multi-dimensional) arrays that might give me a good idea that the question is or not for me right?

Comment: @Trufa perhaps. I'm not sure you need the "complex" tag in your example though. I *know* that multi-dimensional arrays are complicated ;)

Comment: agreed, a little less straight forward there but anyway, if you don't know toyr md arrays, wait for the next question :)